# IBAction methods declared in a Protocol are not visible in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, ibaction

I have defined an objective-c protocol that declares a method that is tagged with IBAction. I implemented a UIViewController that implements the protocol.

In Interface Builder I created a nib file with the UIViewController as the file's owner. However the protocol method is not visible under the Received Actions section although it is tagged as IBAction.

I assume that protocol methods are not visible in Interface Builder. Is that correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`IBAction` is only a `#define` statement; this tag is not inherited when you implement a protocol.

You need to explicitly mark the implemented methods in your class with `IBAction` so Interface builder can pick them up when parsing the header file.